# Updating values in a static html file

Tags: javascript, php, html, integration

I have searched for an answer for this question but cannot find anything that relates directly to the requirement.  Perhaps i'm asking the wrong question and someone could advise how best to do this.

**Requirement:** There is a static HTML file sitting in a file system with values such  as latitude / longitude.  An integration tool receives updated lat/lng values every 2 minutes and these need to be updated in the HTML file so the web page updates a marker with the new co-ords. The integration tool is capable of parsing the html file, opening it for read or replacing it entirely, for example.

**Question:** How best should this be achieved?

For example,

1. I thought of parameterising lat/lng in the html file then using java script or other coding language to update the variables using the data from the integration tool? For info, the integration tool has java, php and other functionality available to parse the html file and update it, etc.

static html before: {lat:12.1234, lng:-12.1234}

static html after: {$lat, $lng}

- Open file for read, replace the variables with the updated values then save / close the file.
- Using (which technique?) the integration tool would update the above values in the html file.

Is there a better or standard way to do this?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

GR

Comment: Do you really want to modify the raw HTML page on the server or can you use a small amount of script that would read the current value and update the value live?

Comment: If you really need a static html, you could simply wrap the values between comments and replace using a regexp keeping the comments, then save the file for next iteration.
`<!--value:lat-->12.1234<!-- -->`

Answer (score -1):

If your integration tool is making an API call to external server and retrieving the lat/lng and then updating HTML file, then I suggest you to make AJAX call from JavaScript and update the lat/lng in HTML at runtime on browser. If there is CORS issue then you can create your on API/Handler in PHP which can be invoked via AJAX call from JavaScript.